# Notation for a sample space

Tags: math-mode

I would like to write the sample space for rolling two fair six-sided dice once. It would look like this:

```
S = {(1, 1), (1, 2), ..., (1, 6),
     (2, 1), (2, 2), ..., (2, 6),
     ...      ...    ...   ...
     (6, 1), (6, 2), ..., (6, 6)}
```

where that third line of "..." is actually vertical.

How can I do this in LaTeX?

Comment: You can use `\vdots` for the vertical dots.

Comment: What about the { and } on different lines in math mode, and getting the ( to line up on each line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can typeset that is to use `align`:

[image]

If you are willing to do a bit more work you could use `alignat` that produces better output:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xcolor}\pagecolor{white}

\newcommand*{\CenterVdots}{\makebox[\widthof{(0,0),}][c]{\vdots}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    S = \{&(1, 1), (1, 2), \dots, (1, 6), \\
          &(2, 1), (2, 2), \dots, (2, 6), \\
          &\CenterVdots  \CenterVdots  \CenterVdots \CenterVdots \\
          &(6, 1), (6, 2), \dots, (6, 6) \}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xcolor}\pagecolor{white}

\newcommand*{\CenterVdots}[1][(0,0),]{\makebox[\widthof{#1}][c]{\vdots}}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{5}
    S = \{&(1, 1), &&\,(1, 2), &&\,\dots, &&\,(1, 6), \\
          &(2, 1), &&\,(2, 2), &&\,\dots, &&\,(2, 6), \\
          &\CenterVdots  &&\,\CenterVdots  &&\,\CenterVdots[\dots] &&\,\CenterVdots \\
          &(6, 1), &&\,(6, 2), &&\,\dots, &&\,(6, 6) \}
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```